# Remove query string from the begging of a url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I've got a buggy query string in my url so it appears in the beginning of a url:
https://website.com/?lang=en/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/image.png
How can I remove this query string so that the url redirects to https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/image.png?
I've tried the following rules to no avail:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "lang=" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)  /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using wordpress, because if that's the case you might've to use wp_rewrite functions.

Comment: Yes, Wordpress. These links are generated by the SrortPixel AI plugin because of the bug. Wasn't able to fix it though.

Answer (score 1):

The path component of your URL is *empty* here, so `RewriteRule ^(.*)` will only capture an empty string, and that means `$1` will be empty as well.

The info you are looking for is in the query string - so you have to capture it from there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1? [R=301,L]
```

`%1` instead of `$1`, because that is a back reference not to the RewriteRule pattern, but to the Condition.

Now this might lead to unexpected results if your query string could ever contain *more* GET parameters after `lang`. In that case, you might have to be a bit more specific with your pattern (like try to match anything after `lang`, that is not an ampersand - `lang=([^&]*)`)